# Very poor file system performance

Tags: c, linux, ext4

I have a function that basically does this:

```
int mmkdir(const char *path, mode_t mode)
{
    struct stat st;
    if (stat(path, &st) < 0)
    {
        if (errno != ENOENT)
            return -1;

        if (mkdir(path, S_IWUSR | S_IRUSR | S_IXUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IXGRP | S_IROTH | S_IXOTH) < 0 && errno != EEXIST)
            return -1;
    }
    else if (!S_ISDIR(st.st_mode))
    {
        errno = ENOTDIR;
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int fun(int id, int id2)
{
    time_t ts;
    struct tm timeinfo;
    char buff[1024], buff1[20], buff2[20], buff3[20];

    ts = time(NULL);
    localtime_r(&ts, &timeinfo);
    strftime(buff1, sizeof(buff1), "%Y%m%d", &timeinfo);
    strftime(buff2, sizeof(buff2), "%H", &timeinfo);

    snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), "%s/%s", dir, buff1);
    if (mmkdir(buff, ORDER_FILE_DEFAULT_PERMS) < 0)
        return -1;

    len = strlen(buff);
    snprintf(buff + len, sizeof(buff) - len, "/%s", buff2);
    if (mmkdir(buff, ORDER_FILE_DEFAULT_PERMS) < 0)
        return -1;
    len += strlen(buff2) + 1;

    strftime(buff3, sizeof(buff2), "%M%S", &timeinfo);
    snprintf(buff + len, sizeof(buff) - len - 1, "/%010d-%04d-%s%s.%s",
         id, id2, buff2, buff3, ext);

    return open(buff, O_WRONLY | O_APPEND | O_CREAT, S_IWUSR | S_IRUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH);
}
```

Plese don't check for errors, it's a working code. It basically calls `stat`(2), `mkdir`(2) (sometimes) and `open`(2).

The problem is that when to I/O load on the server is pretty high, this piece of code sometimes takes even 7s (!!) to complete.

These files that this functions create are located in a folder in /, which is mounted:

```
/dev/md0 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
```

and can be up to 1000 files in a single folder.

What may be the problem? Why this may take so long? Is there any misconfiguration?

I don't ask only for improvements in the code, but in the server configuration also, if possible.

As per request in the comments, the output of `cat /proc/mdstat` is:

```
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md3 : active raid1 sdd1[1] sdc1[0]
      488282000 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

md1 : active raid1 sda2[0] sdb2[1]
      15624120 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

md2 : active raid1 sda3[0] sdb3[1]
      1958900 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

md0 : active raid1 sda1[0] sdb1[1]
      470798200 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
```

that means that the disks are ok

Comment: So when your server is overloaded with I/O, I/O operations take a while? That doesn't really surprise me much.

Comment: "This is not the whole code, why is the whole code slow?" -> We can't answer you that. Apart from what @Mat said

Comment: @Mat yes, that true, but I think 7 seconds it's too much for opening a file.

Comment: @Eregrith the deleted code is outside the timed piece. The stat + open takes 7s, that is the problem

Comment: What's the output of cat /proc/mdstat ?

Comment: @VictorDodon The deleted code can nevertheless influence what's after it.

Comment: @Eregrith the deleted code has nothing to do with the poor performance, I deleted it just because I don't want to show it.

Comment: You might play with [ionice(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ionice.1.html). However, you might also avoid opening a big lot of small files, perhaps using a database like [postgresql](http://postgresql.org/) or simply the [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/) library or some indexed file à la [GDBM](http://www.gnu.org.ua/software/gdbm/manual/gdbm.html)

Comment: @VictorDodon Well maybe. I hope so for you anyway. But if it did you'd never have a solution with what you have shown :). Have you tried the code you posted here as a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://$SITEURL$/help/mcve)?

Comment: There is no upper bound on how long time I/O operations can take. A reasonable estimate is that a file read or write can take as long as the size of your RAM divided by the bandwidth of your disk (completely ignoring seek times on the disk) because in the worst case you've filled all your memory with buffers you want to write out and you have to wait for them before your I/O gets through. So at 100MB/s writes and 4GB of RAM, you can have 40 seconds of I/O queued up. Of course, operating systems are smarter than that in most cases, but 7 seconds isn't very strange at all.

Comment: You could also improve your hardware: use [SSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ssd), buy more RAM to grow the [page cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache). I believe it is more a sysadmin issue than a coding issue.

Comment: I/O scheduler will also affect the wait time of an operation.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I'm also the sysadmin of this server, so I'm interested in the server configuration improvements also

Comment: Try to set `noatime`, `nodiratime`, `delalloc` and `inode_readahead_blks=1024`. Tune as needed. Set `barrier=0`.

Comment: More RAM is the key if disk access is slower than it should. Second measure, of course, as Basile mentioned, is a faster disk. The faster the better. Accessing lots of little files means lots of seek time with a rotating disk which will degrade performance far below max linear throughput. SSD will work wonders there.

Comment: I also notice (iiuc) that raid devices md0, md1 and md2 share a physical disk (sdb). If different processes access md0, md1 and md2 at the same time the disk will have to seek to a different position at each context switch. That will hurt particulariy badly if some accesses are writes because raid1 is underperforming there. (And @alvits hint of skipping access times updates may help.) Perhaps it's possible to move file systems used by other processes to md3, or organize the raids so that md0 has two exclusive physical disks.

Comment: What's the underlying physical disk hardware?  How busy is it?

Answer (score 2):

If this function is called substantially more than once per hour, and the folders are not deleted, then your `mmkdir` calls are redundant. I would implement some kind of caching scheme where you remember the last hour in which you created a folder, and skip creating a new folder if you already created it. This will remove two `stat` calls, which could make a big difference on an overloaded system.

There's likely to be no further improvement you can make to the code alone, since the `open` call would be the only remaining system call, and it cannot be elided without changing the meaning of the function.

Comment: It is a good suggestion, but I don't think it will significantly improve performance. Recent files stay in the page cache, so don't need any disk access.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good idea, but I would like also to know what may be the problem in the server config.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: True, but the page cache may be flushed by the creation of many hundreds or thousands of new files - who knows. Anyway, unfortunately diagnosing the server config is out of scope for this site - try ServerFault maybe.

Comment: @nneonneo - The code calls `open()` on a file under those directories.  All directories on the path to that file are going to be accessed by the kernel anyway when `open()` is called.  Calling `stat()` a few milliseconds earlier is either going to access data already cached by the kernel, or have the kernel effectively prefetch it into cache for the `open()` call.